# AWK print FNR incrementing from 0

Tags: unix, awk

This is the script I'm trying to add a last argument to that prints the FNR into the fourth field.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{ sub(/\r$/,"") }

/^BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT/{
        getline
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    if ($i~/LAB/) a[i]=$i
                }


/^BEGIN_DATA$/,/^END_DATA$/{
             s="";
             if (NF<2) next; else 
                for (j in a)
            s=s?s"\t"$j:$j
            print s 
            }
```

This is what the output from this script looks like:

```
48.34   -55.88  19.19
26.95   24.36   13.43
25.53   4.45    -20.68
71.27   6.68    24.28
...
```

This is my second script:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{ OFS = "\t"; $4="(Untitled "FNR-1")"; print $0 }
```

Piping the first script into the second script returns the **intended result** with the FNR starting from 0 in the fourth field.

```
48.34   -55.88  19.19   (Untitled 0)
26.95   24.36   13.43   (Untitled 1)
25.53   4.45    -20.68  (Untitled 2)
71.27   6.68    24.28   (Untitled 3)
...
```

I tried combining the scripts but I don't get the output I'm trying for.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{ sub(/\r$/,"") }

/^BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT/{
        getline
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    if ($i~/LAB/) a[i]=$i
                }


/^BEGIN_DATA$/,/^END_DATA$/{
             s="";
             if (NF<2) next; else 
                for (j in a)
            s=s?s"\t"$j:$j
            print s 
                        }

    { 
        OFS = "\t"
        $4="(Untitled "FNR-1")"
        print $4 
    }
```

This is the output given. The problem is that it's referencing the same file instead of the output from the last command.

```
(Untitled 0)
(Untitled 1)
(Untitled 2)
(Untitled 3)
(Untitled 4)
(Untitled 5)
(Untitled 6)
(Untitled 7)
(Untitled 8)
(Untitled 9)
(Untitled 10)
(Untitled 11)
(Untitled 13)
(Untitled 14)
(Untitled 15)
48.34   -55.88  19.19
(Untitled 17)
26.95   24.36   13.43
(Untitled 18)
25.53   4.45    -20.68
(Untitled 19)
71.27   6.68    24.28
(Untitled 20)
...
```

I've also tried this:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

{ sub(/\r$/,"") }

/^BEGIN_DATA_FORMAT/{
        getline
            for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                    if ($i~/LAB/) a[i]=$i
                }


/^BEGIN_DATA$/,/^END_DATA$/{
             s="";
             if (NF<2) next; else 
                for (j in a)
            s=s?s"\t"$j:$j

        OFS = "\t"
        $4="(Untitled "FNR-1")"
        print s OFS $4 
            }
```

The output is closer but the problem is that it's still counting from the FNR of that argument. I need it to start at 0.

```
48.34   -55.88  19.19   (Untitled 17)
26.95   24.36   13.43   (Untitled 18)
25.53   4.45    -20.68  (Untitled 19)
71.27   6.68    24.28   (Untitled 20)
...
```

Could someone show me the correct way to combine these scripts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use an incrementing variable rather than the record number:

```
print s, "(Untitled " count++ ")"
```

You should define `OFS` in the `BEGIN` block instead of redefining it for each line.

Instead of doing `{ sub(/\r$/,"") }` why don't you use "dos2unix" on your file first?

Comment: That's another pipe.  Better to reduce the number of tools if you can, isn't it?  I often leave a "grep" out of a string of pipes by putting an extra condition into awk.  This is no different.

Comment: @glenn jackman Thanks, my first time ever hearing of AWK was two weeks ago. I think incrementing a variable was too clear to realize because I was stuck on a specific path. I'm also not using dos2unix to make running this script really the only step needed.

Answer (score 1):

Your first script only prints when the `/^BEGIN_DATA$/,/^END_DATA$/` is met.

Your combined script does its `print s` when the above condition is met, AND does the `print $4` for every line, regardless of whether the condition is met.

As glenn jackman indicated, the problem is that FNR is the "number of records".  When you pipe from one script to another, the second script only gets the output of the first, so each output line is a new record for the second script.

You need a different counter than FNR.

```
BEGIN {
  count=0;
}

...

/^BEGIN_DATA$/,/^END_DATA$/ {
  s="";
  if (NF<2) {
    next;
  } else {
    for (j in a) [
            s=s?s"\t"$j:$j;
    }
    printf("%s\t(Untitled %d)", s, count++);
  }
}
```

Comment: It's not strictly necessary to initialize the variable: awk will treat an undefined variable as zero (in a numeric context) or the empty string.

Comment: I know, but I usually initialize them for clarity.